# How to handle count in recursion

Tags: python, graph, depth-first-search

```
import unittest

def riverSizes(test_input):
   l=[]
   river_sizes = 0
   for i in range(len(test_input)):
       for j in range(len(test_input[i])):
           if test_input[i][j] == 1:
               count = traverse_river(i, j, len(test_input), len(test_input[0]), test_input, 0)
               l.append(count)
               river_sizes += 1
   print(river_sizes,l)

def traverse_river(x, y, max_row, max_col, matrix, count):
    if x < 0 or x >= max_row or y < 0 or y >= max_col or matrix[x][y] != 1:
       return count
    matrix[x][y] = 2
    traverse_river(x - 1, y, max_row, max_col, matrix, count + 1)
    traverse_river(x + 1, y, max_row, max_col, matrix, count + 1)
    traverse_river(x, y + 1, max_row, max_col, matrix, count + 1)
    
class TestProgram(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_case_1(self):
       test_input = [[1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]]
       expected = [1, 2, 2, 2, 5]
       riverSizes(test_input)
       self.assertEqual(sorted(riverSizes(test_input)), expected)
```

I am trying to run dfs on the matrix and keep track of all the connected components with "1" along with the length count of connected ones. How to handle count in recusrrsion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues with the code:

- The function `riverSizes` does not return anything, so applying `sorted` on it will not help either.
- The recursion should also consider `y - 1`, as it may be that there is a U-shape, like this pattern:

  ```
    1 0 1
    1 1 1
  ```

  ...and you don't want to miss out on the 1 in the top-right corner.
- The function `traverse_river` does not always return a count -- only if the first `if` condition is true.

Moreover, you don't need:

- to pass `count` as an argument. Just add to the returned count to so accumulate that value.
- to maintain `river_sizes`, as that is duplicate information: it is actually equal to `len(l)`.

Here is how it could work:

```
def riverSizes(test_input):
   l = []
   for i in range(len(test_input)):
       for j in range(len(test_input[i])):
           if test_input[i][j] == 1:
               count = traverse_river(i, j, len(test_input), len(test_input[0]), test_input)
               l.append(count)
   return l

def traverse_river(x, y, max_row, max_col, matrix):
    if x < 0 or x >= max_row or y < 0 or y >= max_col or matrix[x][y] != 1:
       return 0
    matrix[x][y] = 2
    return (1 + traverse_river(x - 1, y, max_row, max_col, matrix)
              + traverse_river(x + 1, y, max_row, max_col, matrix)
              + traverse_river(x, y + 1, max_row, max_col, matrix)
              + traverse_river(x, y - 1, max_row, max_col, matrix))
    
test_input = [[1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]]
print(riverSizes(test_input))
```